# HttpContext User value changing on its own?

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, genericprincipal

I'm working on an ASP.Net 2.0 application and am having a strange issue involving the HttpContext User.  It appears to be changing on its own when I go to a particular page/directory.

All of our pages inherit from a base page.  In that base page's Page_Load() method we run an authorization check to see if the user can see the page they're going to.

We retrieve the user to check against with this code:

```
GenericPrincipal objPrincipal = (GenericPrincipal)Context.User;
```

When I go to this unusual directory the User value isn't me, it's some other username I've never heard of.  This username isn't authorized to see these pages, so authorization fails.

This mysterious directory isn't a virtual web, just a regular directory in our website, *however* I've noticed it has its own Web.Config file.  I'm guessing that's a cause of the trouble here.

My question is, how can I investigate this further, in determining what's changing the User value when I go to this directory?

[edit] -- when I remove or rename the web.config file in this directory, the User value no longer changes.  However, as mentioned in a comment below there's no  value in it so I'm not sure how the Principal.User value could change based simply on the presence of the file?  Must be something I'm missing of course.

Comment: Is there a web.config in that directory that specifies impersonation?
If not I would look at the web app web.config, to make sure impersonation isnt on.

Comment: There's no identity impersonation settings in that web.config unfortunately.  It would have made sense if so.

Comment: Sometimes there are more than one web.config - another one with security information at a lower level. Just for sanity.

Comment: Also - what is the username? It will help.